# nextAll(), prevAll(), next() and prev() doesn't return results

Tags: jquery

This is my js module:

```
let rating = (() => {

    let rate = (elem) => {
        if($(elem).hasClass('checked'))
            unmarkStars($(elem))
        else
            markStars($(elem))
    }

    let unmarkStars = (elem) => {
        console.log(elem.nextAll('.fa-star'))
        elem.nextAll('.fa-star').removeClass('checked')
    }

    let markStars = (elem) => {
        console.log(elem.prevAll('.fa-star'))
        elem.prevAll('.fa-star').addClass('checked')
    }

    return {
        rate: rate
    }

})()
```

When I click on element from this `ul`:

```
<ul id="rating-select">
    <li><span onclick="rating.rate(this)" class="fa fa-star checked"></span></li>
    <li><span onclick="rating.rate(this)" class="fa fa-star checked"></span></li>
    <li><span onclick="rating.rate(this)" class="fa fa-star checked"></span></li>
    <li><span onclick="rating.rate(this)" class="fa fa-star checked"></span></li>
    <li><span onclick="rating.rate(this)" class="fa fa-star "></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

there is empty result in the console. Seems like `nextAll` neither `nextPrev` returns any results. I red the `jQuery` documentation, searched around for what the problem can be but still can't get it. It seems alright for me. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextAll` & `prevAll` methods return siblings next & prev to it respectively. You should select the parent `li` using `parent` method and then select next/prev `li`'s and finally find `.fa-star`.

```
elem.parent().nextAll('li').find('.fa-star')

elem.parent().prevAll('li').find('.fa-star')
```